# How to draw dashed lines with using rectangles in AS3?

Tags: actionscript-3, line, draw, rectangles

I'm using starling framework for my game project and it hasn't got any draw dashed line method. Because of this they suggest me to draw dashed lines with using small rectangles which is called quads.

My math is not enough for it, could you give a sample method for rectangles with dashed lines occurring.

[image: Drawing dashed lines with using rectangles]

Thanks..

Comment: Paint this horizontally in shape, then rotate shape.

Comment: What is preventing you from using Flash's own graphics class to draw the line? Take a look at http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/Graphics.html and the example shown for the moveTo() method , which shows how to do a dashed line.

Answer (score 1):

This class by [Andy Woodruff](http://andywoodruff.com/blog/drawing-dashed-lines-with-actionscript-3/) draws dashed lines

```
/* 
DashedLine class
by Andy Woodruff (http://cartogrammar.com/blog || awoodruff@gmail.com)
May 2008
Still in progress; I'll get a more perfected version eventually. For now take it as is.

This is a Sprite with the capability to do basic lineTo drawing with dashed lines.
Example:
    var dashy:DashedLine = new DashedLine(2,0x333333,new Array(3,3,10,3,5,8,7,13));
    dashy.moveTo(120,120);
    dashy.beginFill(0xcccccc);
    dashy.lineTo(220,120);
    dashy.lineTo(220,220);
    dashy.lineTo(120,220);
    dashy.lineTo(120,120);
    dashy.endFill();
*/

package com.cartogrammar.drawing {

    import flash.display.Shape;
    import flash.display.Sprite;
    import flash.geom.Point;
    import flash.display.CapsStyle;

    public class DashedLine extends Sprite {

        var lengthsArray:Array = new Array();   // array of dash and gap lengths (dash,gap,dash,gap....)
        var lineColor:uint; // line color
        var lineWeight:Number;  // line weight
        var lineAlpha:Number = 1;   // line alpha
        var curX:Number = 0;    // stores current x as it changes with lineTo and moveTo calls
        var curY:Number = 0;    // same as above, but for y
        var remainingDist:Number = 0;   // stores distance between the end of the last full dash or gap and the end coordinates specified in lineTo
        var curIndex = null;    // current index in the length array, so we know which dash or gap to draw
        var arraySum:Number = 0;    // total length of the dashes and gaps... not currently being used for anything, but maybe useful?
        var startIndex:int = 0; // array index (the particular dash or gap) to start with in a lineTo--based on the last dash or gap drawn in the previous lineTo (along with remainingDist, this is so our line can properly continue around corners!)

        var fill:Shape = new Shape();   // shappe in the background to be used for fill (if any)
        var stroke:Shape = new Shape(); // shape in the foreground to be used for the dashed line

        public function DashedLine(weight:Number = 0, color:Number = 0, lengthsArray:Array = null){

            if (lengthsArray != null){  // if lengths array was specified, use it
                this.lengthsArray = lengthsArray;
            } else {    // if unspecified, use a default 5-5 line
                this.lengthsArray = [5,5];
            }
            if (this.lengthsArray.length % 2 != 0){ // if array has more dashes than gaps (i.e. an odd number of values), add a 5 gap to the end
                lengthsArray.push(5);
            }

            // sum the dash and gap lengths
            for (var i:int in lengthsArray){
                arraySum += lengthsArray[i];
            }

            // set line weight and color properties from constructor arguments
            lineWeight = weight;
            lineColor = color;

            // set the lineStyle according to specified properties - beyond weight and color, we use the defaults EXCEPT no line caps, as they interfere with the desired gaps
            stroke.graphics.lineStyle(lineWeight,lineColor,lineAlpha,false,"none",CapsStyle.NONE);

            // add fill and stroke shapes
            addChild(fill);
            addChild(stroke);
        }

        // basic moveTo method
        public function moveTo(x:Number,y:Number):void{
            stroke.graphics.moveTo(x,y);    // move to specified x and y
            fill.graphics.moveTo(x,y);
            // keep track of x and y
            curX = x;   
            curY = y;
            // reset remainingDist and startIndex - if we are moving away from last line segment, the next one will start at the beginning of the dash-gap sequence
            remainingDist = 0;
            startIndex = 0;
        }

        // lineTo method
        public function lineTo(x:Number,y:Number):void{
            var slope:Number = (y - curY)/(x - curX);   // get slope of segment to be drawn
            // record beginning x and y
            var startX:Number = curX;
            var startY:Number = curY;
            // positive or negative direction for each x and y?
            var xDir:int = (x < startX) ? -1 : 1;
            var yDir:int = (y < startY) ? -1 : 1;
            // keep drawing dashes and gaps as long as either the current x or y is not beyond the destination x or y
            outerLoop : while (Math.abs(startX-curX) < Math.abs(startX-x) || Math.abs(startY-curY) < Math.abs(startY-y)){
                // loop through the array to draw the appropriate dash or gap, beginning with startIndex (either 0 or determined by the end of the last lineTo)
                for (var i:int = startIndex; i < lengthsArray.length; i++){
                        var dist:Number = (remainingDist == 0) ? lengthsArray[i] : remainingDist;   // distance to draw is either the dash/gap length from the array or remainingDist left over from the last lineTo if there is any
                        // get increments of x and y based on distance, slope, and direction - see getCoords()
                        var xInc:Number = getCoords(dist,slope).x * xDir;
                        var yInc:Number = getCoords(dist,slope).y * yDir;
                        // if the length of the dash or gap will not go beyond the destination x or y of the lineTo, draw the dash or gap
                        if (Math.abs(startX-curX) + Math.abs(xInc) < Math.abs(startX-x) || Math.abs(startY-curY) + Math.abs(yInc) < Math.abs(startY-y)){
                            if (i % 2 == 0){    // if even index in the array, it is a dash, hence lineTo
                                stroke.graphics.lineTo(curX + xInc,curY + yInc);
                            } else {    // if odd, it's a gap, so moveTo
                                stroke.graphics.moveTo(curX + xInc,curY + yInc);
                            }
                            // keep track of the new x and y
                            curX += xInc;
                            curY += yInc;
                            curIndex = i;   // store the current dash or gap (array index)
                            // reset startIndex and remainingDist, as these will only be non-zero for the first loop (through the array) of the lineTo
                            startIndex = 0;
                            remainingDist = 0;
                        } else {    // if the dash or gap can't fit, break out of the loop
                            remainingDist = getDistance(curX,curY,x,y); // get the distance between the end of the last dash or gap and the destination x/y
                            curIndex = i;   // store the current index
                            break outerLoop;    // break out of the while loop
                        }
                }
            }

            startIndex = curIndex;  // for next time, the start index is the last index used in the loop

            if (remainingDist != 0){    // if there is a remaining distance, line or move from current x/y to the destination x/y
                if (curIndex % 2 == 0){ // even = dash
                    stroke.graphics.lineTo(x,y);
                } else {    // odd = gap
                    stroke.graphics.moveTo(x,y);
                }
                remainingDist = lengthsArray[curIndex] - remainingDist; // remaining distance (which will be used at the beginning of the next lineTo) is now however much is left in the current dash or gap after that final lineTo/moveTo above
            } else {    // if there is no remaining distance (i.e. the final dash or gap fits perfectly), we're done with the current dash or gap, so increment the start index for next time
                if (startIndex == lengthsArray.length - 1){ // go to the beginning of the array if we're at the end
                    startIndex = 0;
                } else {
                    startIndex++;
                }
            }
            // at last, the current x and y are the destination x and y
            curX = x;
            curY = y;

            fill.graphics.lineTo(x,y);  // simple lineTo (invisible line) on the fill shape so that the fill (if one was started via beginFill below) follows along with the dashed line
        }

        // returns a point with the vertical and horizontal components of a diagonal given the distance and slope
        private function getCoords(distance:Number,slope:Number):Point {
            var angle:Number = Math.atan(slope);    // get the angle from the slope
            var vertical:Number = Math.abs(Math.sin(angle)*distance);   // vertical from sine of angle and length of hypotenuse - using absolute value here and applying negative as needed in lineTo, because this number doesn't always turn out to be negative or positive exactly when I want it to (haven't thought through the math enough yet to figure out why)
            var horizontal:Number = Math.abs(Math.cos(angle)*distance); // horizontal from cosine
            return new Point(horizontal,vertical);  // return the point         
        }

        // basic Euclidean distance
        private function getDistance(startX:Number,startY:Number,endX:Number,endY:Number):Number{
            var distance:Number = Math.sqrt(Math.pow((endX-startX),2) + Math.pow((endY-startY),2));
            return distance;
        }

        // clear everything and reset the lineStyle
        public function clear():void{
            stroke.graphics.clear();
            stroke.graphics.lineStyle(lineWeight,lineColor,lineAlpha,false,"none",CapsStyle.NONE);
            fill.graphics.clear();
            moveTo(0,0);
        }

        // set lineStyle with specified weight, color, and alpha
        public function lineStyle(w:Number=0,c:Number=0,a:Number=1):void{
            lineWeight = w;
            lineColor = c;
            lineAlpha = a;
            stroke.graphics.lineStyle(lineWeight,lineColor,lineAlpha,false,"none",CapsStyle.NONE);
        }

        // basic beginFill
        public function beginFill(c:uint,a:Number=1):void{
            fill.graphics.beginFill(c,a);
        }
        // basic endFill
        public function endFill():void{
            fill.graphics.endFill();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks For Your Replies, I Wrote My Own Class Which Draws Rectangles To Create A Dashed Lines.

Thanks..

Comment: Can you post the code? It may help others with similar issues in the future.